# Can you stop checking a if once it has passed once, in a while loop?

Tags: java, loops

I don't need the if after its condition has been met. Is there any way I can modify my code so that it doesn't have to check for it after it passed?
 I have a lot of tables in my database and I'm wondering if the code is optimal.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STACKOVERFLOW.information_schema.tables ORDER BY TABLE_NAME");
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
    ExtractFrom.addItem(name);         
    if (name.toLowerCase().equals("stack")) pvIsPresent=true;
}
if (pvIsPresent)
    ExtractFrom.setSelectedItem("stack");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somehow ugly but...

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STACKOVERFLOW.information_schema.tables ORDER BY TABLE_NAME");

while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
    ExtractFrom.addItem(name);

    if (name.toLowerCase().equals("stack")) {
        pvIsPresent = true;
        break;
    }
}

while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
    ExtractFrom.addItem(name);
}

if (pvIsPresent)
    ExtractFrom.setSelectedItem("stack");
```

Comment: It's very ugly but it's exactly what I asked for!

Answer (score 5):

You could just do `if (!pvIsPresent && name.toLowerCase().equals("stack"))`.

Although you might also want to use the slightly more efficient `name.equalsIgnoreCase("stack")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the while statement to this:

```
while(rs.next && !pvIsPresent)...
```

Comment: then the while would stop

Comment: but if you're just looking to see if that is present a single time, then you wouldn't need to continue the while loop, correct?

Comment: nah, I need to populate my field with all the data, then after, I'm setting the selecteditem to a particular item if it was present.

Answer (score 0):

More ugly and more simply maybe but you can put a counter before while as

- "int counter = 0"

and in the if statement you can ask as

- "if(..... && counter == 0)"

than after if statement you can increment the counter as

- "counter++"

than since the counter never become 0 again the if statement never be checked again.

I hope it helps too.